# Looking for a formula used by VE6YP trap calculator

Tags: antenna-theory, software, software-development, trap

I wonder whether the source code of VE6YP (Tony Field) coaxtrap design program ([link 1](https://www.qsl.net/ve6yp/index.html), [link 2](http://www.cqham.ru/coaxtrap.htm)) was ever published or described. As a Mac user I'm having little difficulties using this software and I would like to rewrite it in Python. Or maybe there are similar calculators available online? Unfortunately I didn't manage to find one.

Comment: I don't see another calculator. Starting with coax spec pF/m and form diameter, increase turns until length x pF/m resonates with inductance calculated using "wire" of coax shield's diameter on chosen form.

Comment: Have you asked Tony?